# Why aftr the SSL program (client/server openssl) Wireshark shows me the protocol X11 & TCP and not SSL or TLS?

Tags: sockets, ssl, openssl, wireshark

The question is in the title ?

When i make the transfer of data in localhost i was waiting to see a protocol SSL at least in one communication via wireshark ? What am I mssing ?

it shows also malformed packet o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you've used a port usually associated with X (like 6000). Anyway, you can change the interpretation with "Analyze|Decode As"